# How do I convert my File.Contains to do Regex?

Tags: c#, asp.net

a brief background to what I am trying to do, I have a button upload that can select multiple files. and I am trying to match a filename with a dateformat, and if matches I will do something.

**How to Apply this code to my Code?**

```
            string testDate = "3214312402-17-2013143214214";
            Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}");
            Match mat = rgx.Match(testDate);
            Console.WriteLine(mat.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
```

**My Code**

```
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
                HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;

                for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (hfc[i].FileName.Contains("2018-4-8 20-13-34"))
                    {
                        Response.Write(hfc[i].FileName + "Test");
                        hfc[i].SaveAs(@path + "\\" + hfc[i].FileName + "Test");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.Write(hfc[i].FileName);
                        hfc[i].SaveAs(@path + "\\" + hfc[i].FileName);
                    }

                }
```

My code above works well, but my only problem, this can only work for a specific filename with that specific date, I need to apply a regex code for Contains, and base on what I've researched so far, Contains only detect the exact string, unlike regex which can be used for detecting specific formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```cs
hfc[i].FileName.Contains("2018-4-8 20-13-34")
```

For

```cs
Regex.IsMatch(hfc[i].FileName, @"\d{4}-\d-\d \d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}")
```